# Can't add SQL Server CE database using SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, ssms, northwind

I'm trying to add the Northwind SQL Server CE 3.5 version which is an `.sdf` to SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 but I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to retrieve data for this request.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
>
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object
>   connectionInfo, Request request)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.AttachDatabaseData.PrimaryFile.GetOriginalDatabaseName(String
>   primaryFilePath)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.AttachDatabaseData.PrimaryFile.PopulatePrimaryFileData(String
>   primaryFilePath)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.AttachDatabaseData.PrimaryFile..ctor(SqlManagementUserControl
>   parent, CDataContainer dc, String fullPath, String databaseOwner,
>   ServerConnection connectionInfo)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.AttachDatabase.IsSelectedFileValid(BrowseFolder
>   dlg)
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteReader(String
>   sqlCommand, SqlCommand& command)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecuteSql.GetDataReader(String
>   query, SqlCommand& command)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataProvider.SetConnectionAndQuery(ExecuteSql
>   execSql, String query)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecuteSql.GetDataProvider(StringCollection
>   query, Object con, StatementBuilder sb, RetriveMode rm)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecuteSql.ExecuteWithResults(StringCollection
>   query, Object con, StatementBuilder sb)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.FillData(ResultType
>   resultType, StringCollection sql, Object connectionInfo,
>   StatementBuilder sb)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.FillDataWithUseFailure(SqlEnumResult
>   sqlresult, ResultType resultType)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.BuildResult(EnumResult
>   result)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.PrimaryFile.GetData(EnumResult
>   erParent)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData(Request
>   req, Object ci)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.GetData(Object
>   connectionInfo, Request request)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object
>   connectionInfo, Request request)
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact
>   Edition\v3.5\Samples\Northwind_ce.sdf is not a primary database file.
>   (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Comment: You can use [SQL Server CE Query Tool][1]


  [1]: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33433/SQL-Server-CE-Query-Tool

Comment: @BizApps How can I get that to export the database so that sql server management studio can read it as an SQL CE datrabase? Or isthat not possible through that tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL CE database cannot be attached to MS SQL Server. But you can use third-part tools to migrate your database from SQL CE to MS SQL Server. For example, you can use [exportsqlce utility](http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/).